# Deserializing xml ignoring parent elements

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have the following XML:

```
<response>
    <error>Error Text</error>
    <results>
        <parent>
            <dataarray>
                <data>blah blah blah</data>
                <data>blah blah blah</data>
                <data>blah blah blah</data>
                <data>blah blah blah</data>
            </dataarray>
        </parent>
    </results>
</response>
```

I need to deserialize this into the following class

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("result")]
    public string Error { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("results")]
    public MyResult Result { get; set; }
}


public class MyResult 
{
    [XmlArray("dataarray")]
    [XmlArrayItem("data")]
    public List<string> Data{ get; set; }
}
```

However due to the data array being within the `parent` element this does not work.
I know i can solve this by creating another class for the parent element and put the data array into that but that seems wasteful.

Is there a way I use the above class structure?

Comment: Use Linq2Xml...`xDocument.Descendants("data")`

Comment: @L.B I asked how to do this using Deserialization.

Comment: Therefore I *commented* not answered.

Comment: not sure if this may work or even work at all, `[XmlArray("parent/dataarray")]` or `[XmlElement("results/parent")]`. on otherside you seems to have the nice solution unless can change the xml structure. custom serialization may also help in this case, but may introduce even more code then introducing a new class and mark with attribute.

Comment: @pushpraj Thanks for the suggestions but they don't work.